# Display a StorageFile in Windows 8 Metro C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to display an image file on the UI from the Assets. I managed to store the item as a `StorageFile`. How can I display it? I've tried to display it in a XAML `<Image>` tag's Source. Is it possible to covert `StorageFile` to `Image`?

```
string path = @"Assets\mypicture.png";
StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(path);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this function

```
public async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(StorageFile storageFile)
{
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = bitmapImage;
        return image;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmapAsync(StorageFile storageFile)
{
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStream> read = storageFile.OpenReadAsync();
    IRandomAccessStream stream = await read;
    bitmap.SetSource(stream);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Call the function this way:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = await GetBitmapAsync (file);
```

Comment: It says Cannot convert type `'Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType'` to `'Windows.Storage.Streams.FileRandomAccessStream'`

Answer (score 1):

> image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("file://"+ storageFile.Path))

Comment: This wont work for files that are not in the app local storage, such as images in the images library. The path cannot be used to access those external files in a Windows Store app, only the StorageFile object.