# How to get thumbnail from a video in Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am currently working on an app in which there is feature to record video. I am aware about how to record the video and save it in `localFolder` of app. My problem is that I need to show a thumbnail to user after he records the video. So, for that I want to extract the first frame from the recorded video. The final video is stored in `StorageFile` object but I am not aware how to get image from `StorageFile` object.

Please can anyone suggest with some sample code how can I do that. I am using default Camera API for recording video. My code is below

```
private async void CaptureVideo()
{
    CameraCaptureUI cameraUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
    cameraUI.VideoSettings.Format=CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat.Mp4;
    cameraUI.VideoSettings.MaxDurationInSeconds = 10;
    StorageFile capturedVideo = await cameraUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Video);
    string videoName="video_" + GetDateTimestamp() +".mp4";
    if(capturedVideo !=null)
    {
        saveVideoandShowThumbnail(capturedVideo, videoName);
    }
}
```

Here in **saveVideoandShowThumbnail()** method is to store the video in Videos Folder and generate the thumbnail.

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660077/display-a-storagefile-in-windows-8-metro-c-sharp

Comment: Will this work in case of Video also?

Comment: Bdw you have an option of getting thumnail as `capturedVideo.getThumbnailAsync(mode).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );` where mode is the ThumbnailMode

Comment: Use `StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync` you can get a thumbnail of the video file, there is gotcha according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26170732/815938) that you need to move the video to public Video Library first.

Comment: I can't move it to public directory, please let me know without that is there any other workaround?

Comment: @GopeshSharma The first link only works if StorageFile contains an Image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync()* solved my issue. I tried to show image from video using below code. Hope it helps someone

```
bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(await videoFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem));
```